# I have installed hadoop 2. 6 on ubuntu 14.04 i need help in running it

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed single node cluster hadoop 2.6 and all the nodes are running, but when i try to put a sample text file into the hdfs its not working, I have started to learn hadoop so pls be explanatory it would be helpful. I need help with command for putting the test file into hdfs and performing a simple computation on the text file. the tutorials found in web are confusing as some of the commands differ for different hadoop and ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a file into the HDFS, you can use the `put` command as shown under:

```
hadoop fs -put path-in-your-local-filesystem path-in-HDFS
```

Note that if you want to put your file within a new directory in HDFS, `put` will not create the directory itself. You need to `mkdir` first as shown: (`-p` to create parent directories as needed)

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/input
hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/Desktop/input-file /user/input
```

(assuming input-file saved on hduser's Desktop)

To perform computations on the file using Hadoop, you need to write `map` and `reduce` functions. I would suggest you to start with the Word Count program to start learning MapReduce Programming. You can refer to Hadoop: The Definitive Guide.

Next, you need to compile your java source file (say WordCount.java) using:

```
sudo javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar WordCount.java
```

Next, create a jar file with all the classes using

```
jar -cvf wc WordCount*.class
```

where wc is the name of the newly created jar.

Next, run the program using

```
hadoop jar jar-name main-class-name input-path-in-HDFS output-path-in-HDFS
```

For this example, you can use

```
hadoop jar wc WordCount /user/input/input-file /user/output
```

It will create the output directory automatically in HDFS.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you , can you please tell me how to interface eclipse ide so it would be more simple to compile and execute.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unaware of the details of Hadoop integration with Eclipse.. Never tried it :(